# When Zoomed the canvas and then pan, now if I am trying to drag the objects within canvas then not able to do so. But canvas is panning only

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, 3d, 2d

1) Without scaling / zooming I am able to pan canvas and able to drag images.

2) Able to drag images within canvas if scaling / zooming.

3) **But When I pan the canvas after zooming then if I am trying to drag images then just canvas is panning. Not able to drag the images**

In imagesHitTests(x, y) and imagesHitTests2(x, y) we are finding the hits on images drawn on main svg file.

There are points panX and panY. How should I solve this?

Following is my code:

```
var dataJSON = data || [];
var dataJSON2 = data2 || [];
window.onload = function(){       
    var canvas=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");        

    var canvasOffset=$("#myCanvas").offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;

    var lastX=0;
    var lastY=0;
    var panX=0;
    var panY=0;
    var dragging=[];
    var dragging2=[];
    var isDown=false;

    function loadImages(sources, callback){
      var images = {};
      var loadImages = 0;
      var numImages = 0;
      //get num of sources
      for(var i in sources){            
        numImages++;
      }
      for(var i in sources){            
        images[i] = new Image();
        images[i].onload = function(){
          if(++loadImages >= numImages){
            callback(images);
          }
        };
        images[i].src = sources[i];            
      }
    }

    var sources = {darthVader : '/static/images/orange1.png', yoda : '/static/images/green1.png'};


    // load the tiger svg file
    var svgfiles = ["/static/images/awesome_tiger.svg"];       

    function draw(scaleValue){ 
      ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);    
      ctx.save();
      ctx.drawSvg(svgfiles[0],panX,panY,400*scaleValue, 400*scaleValue);

      loadImages(sources, function(images){     
        ctx.scale(scaleValue, scaleValue);
        for(var i = 0, pos; pos = dataJSON[i]; i++) {            
          ctx.drawImage(images.darthVader, parseInt(parseInt(pos.x) + parseInt(panX)), parseInt(parseInt(pos.y) + parseInt(panY)), 20/scaleValue, 20/scaleValue);               
        }
        for(var i = 0, pos; pos = dataJSON2[i]; i++) {            
          ctx.drawImage(images.yoda, parseInt(parseInt(pos.x) + parseInt(panX)), parseInt(parseInt(pos.y) + parseInt(panY)), 20/scaleValue, 20/scaleValue);              
        }
        ctx.restore();
      });

    };
    var scaleValue = 1;
    var scaleMultiplier = 0.8;
    draw(scaleValue);
    var startDragOffset = {};
    var mouseDown = false;          
    // add button event listeners
    document.getElementById("plus").addEventListener("click", function(){           
        scaleValue /= scaleMultiplier;  
        //checkboxZoomPan();            
        draw(scaleValue);               
    }, false);
     document.getElementById("minus").addEventListener("click", function(){
        scaleValue *= scaleMultiplier;
        //checkboxZoomPan();            
        draw(scaleValue);       
    }, false);
    document.getElementById("original_size").addEventListener("click", function(){
        scaleValue = 1;
        //checkboxZoomPan();            
        draw(scaleValue);   
    }, false);


    // create an array of any "hit" colored-images
    function imagesHitTests(x,y){
      // adjust for panning
      x-=panX;
      y-=panY;
      // create var to hold any hits
      var hits=[];
      // hit-test each image
      // add hits to hits[]
      loadImages(sources, function(images){
        for(var i = 0, pos; pos = dataJSON[i]; i++) {              
           if(x >= parseInt(parseInt(pos.x) * scaleValue) && x <= parseInt(parseInt(pos.x) * scaleValue + parseInt(20)) && y >= parseInt(parseInt(pos.y) * scaleValue) && y <= parseInt(parseInt(pos.y) * scaleValue + parseInt(20))){  
            hits.push(i);              
          }              
        }            
      });          
      return(hits);
    }

    function imagesHitTests2(x,y){
      // adjust for panning
      x-=panX;
      y-=panY;
      // create var to hold any hits
      var hits2=[];
      // hit-test each image
      // add hits to hits[]
      loadImages(sources, function(images){            
        for(var i = 0, pos; pos = dataJSON2[i]; i++) {
           if(x >= parseInt(parseInt(pos.x) * scaleValue) && x <= parseInt(parseInt(pos.x) * scaleValue + parseInt(20)) && y >= parseInt(parseInt(pos.y) * scaleValue) && y <= parseInt(parseInt(pos.y) * scaleValue + parseInt(20))){  
            hits2.push(i);                
          }              
        }            
      });          
      return(hits2);
    }

    function handleMouseDown(e){
      // get mouse coordinates
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
      // set the starting drag position
      lastX=mouseX;
      lastY=mouseY;
      // test if we're over any of the images
      dragging=imagesHitTests(mouseX,mouseY);
      dragging2=imagesHitTests2(mouseX,mouseY);
      // set the dragging flag

      isDown=true;
    }

    function handleMouseUp(e){
      // clear the dragging flag
      isDown=false;
    }

    function handleMouseMove(e){
      // if we're not dragging, exit
      if(!isDown){
        return;
      }

      //get mouse coordinates
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // calc how much the mouse has moved since we were last here
      var dx=mouseX-lastX;
      var dy=mouseY-lastY;

      // set the lastXY for next time we're here
      lastX=mouseX;
      lastY=mouseY;

      // handle drags/pans
      if(dragging.length>0){           
        // we're dragging images
        // move all affected images by how much the mouse has moved            
        for(var i = 0, pos; pos = dataJSON[dragging[i]]; i++) {              
          pos.x = parseInt(pos.x) + parseInt(dx);              
          pos.y = parseInt(pos.y) + parseInt(dy);              
        }
      }
      else if(dragging2.length>0){            
        for(var i = 0, pos1; pos1 = dataJSON2[dragging2[i]]; i++) {              
          pos1.x = parseInt(pos1.x) + parseInt(dx);              
          pos1.y = parseInt(pos1.y) + parseInt(dy);
        }            
      }
      else{
        // we're panning the tiger
        // set the panXY by how much the mouse has moved
        panX+=dx;
        panY+=dy;
      }
      draw(scaleValue);
    }

    // use jQuery to handle mouse events
    $("#myCanvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
    $("#myCanvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
    $("#myCanvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});   
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you must change coordinates and width\height of image on your scale

You want to do something like this - http://drag.com.hostinghood.com/?

Comment: link you given is correct. But Similar thing I want to do after panning. Without zoom if I pan then able to drag images. But if I zoom/scale then if I pan then not able to drag those images.

Comment: maybe you should draw image like that? ctx.drawImage(images.darthVader, parseInt(parseInt(pos.x)*scaleValue + parseInt(panX)*scaleValue, parseInt(parseInt(pos.y)*scaleValue + parseInt(panY)*scaleValue)) and the same with width and height of image

Comment: Tried ctx.drawImage(images.orange, parseInt(parseInt(pos.x) * scaleValue + parseInt(panX) * scaleValue)/scaleValue, parseInt(parseInt(pos.y) * scaleValue + parseInt(panY) * scaleValue)/scaleValue, 20/scaleValue, 20/scaleValue);   But not working

Comment: Any other options please?

Comment: If I replace this :

x-=panX;

y-=panY;

With :

x-=panX * scaleValue;

y-=panY * scaleValue;

Then after zoom if I pan the canvas then able to drag images.
But While panning the canvas , images drawn on it are getting translate(Changing their position).

Comment: In my example, I made a pan with CSS, but not sure if it right for you.

here is example on panning image(is easy to do the same to canvas)
https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/spryMap.zip?w=AACyEHE9jTIqVrU4RUbMG6MSdOK1QFrF2PY5V73-O4I9jA&dl=1

Comment: This is Solved. Thank you all